# MYSQL - Find the column has distinct values or not..?

Tags: mysql, distinct-values

I have a table in mysql-4.1.22 with huge set of data. And I want to check whether the particular column in my table has distinct values or not(No need to retrieve all distinct values). I have googled and try MYSQL inbuilt function distinct and alternative group by solution but both takes too much amount of time to execute.

Is there any other way to find a column has distinct values or not? . Kindly share your ideas.

Comment: don't you have index defined on your column

Comment: 1. does the table have index on this column? 2. how many records does the table hold? 3. without querying the table you can't know what's inside...

Comment: What exactly do you mean. Do you want to see if all the rows in the whole column have just 1 value or not?

Comment: I want to make sure that the corresponding column does not have repeated/non unique values.(i.e) It may contain(1,2,3..) and not (1,2,3,1..)

Answer (score 3):

```sql
SELECT count(*), count(colname), count(distinct colname)
  FROM tabname;
```

1. First `count()` will give you total number of rows in the `tabname`;
2. Second one will give you the number of `NOT NULL` values in you desired `colname`;
3. And the last one will give you a number of distinct values in the desired `colname`.

Answer (score 0):

select count(*) from  group by  having count(*)>1;